# Case Escalation Rules : ISCHANGED(Status)

Tags: escalation

When we do a dummy update on the case the escalation rule moves out from the monitoring queue. I guess it happens when we have ISCHANGED(Status) in the escalation rule.

Please find the below escalation rule which we have.

```
AND(Account.area__c = 'Titalad', ISPICKVAL(Status,"Rejected"), Original_Case_Requestor__r.On_Leave__c, ISCHANGED(Status) ).
```

We would like to know if it is a standard behavior of salesforce when the case is updated with an dummy update,  it will move the escalation rule from the monitoring queue.

Is there any workaround instead of using the ISCHANGED can we use something else ?

Answer (score 3):

Escalation rules are fired at the moment a record is saved, not later. Your rule, therefore, has several potential difficulties. For example, if the case is created and the `Original_Case_Requestor__r.On_Leave__c` is *false*, but subsequently turns *true* after the case was saved, the escalation rule won't have a chance to be placed in to the queue unless the case is subsequently edited again. While I can't say exactly what's failing here, the `Account.Area__c`, `Original_Case_Requestor__r.On_Leave__c` and `ISCHANGED` parts may all be problematic to your escalation rule. You might need a Process Builder or some other technique to update the cases when the user or account changes, and you might want to remove the `ISCHANGED` requirement.